# React Native AsyncStorage.getItem is not working. ({"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null})

Tags: react-native, async-await, apollo, apollo-client, asyncstorage

Good day! I have this function of AsyncStorage that gets an item of a token. I used with ApolloClient to process the token but when I test it first, it seems to have an error with what will I get by AsyncStorage function.

```html
export function jwtLogin(data) {
  return async dispatch => {
    const userData = {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
    };
    console.log(userData);
    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: new HttpLink({
        uri: API_URL,
      }),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
    client
      .mutate({
        mutation: loginUser,
        variables: {
          email: userData.email,
          password: userData.password,
        },
      })
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data.tokenCreate);
        console.log('Token', resp.data.tokenCreate.token);
        if (resp.data.tokenCreate.token !== null) {
          saveJWTTokenData(resp.data.tokenCreate.token); //from AsyncStorage save function

          async function main() { //function of AsyncStorage
            await AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt_token').then(item => {
              return item;
            });
          }
          console.log(main()); // returns error
          Actions.push('main_loading');
        } else {
          const errors = resp.data.tokenCreate.errors;
          {
            errors.map(err => {
              Alert.alert('Error.', err.message);
            });
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Alert.alert('Error.', err.message);
      });
  };
}
```

For the save storage function:

```
export const saveJWTTokenData = async jwt_token => AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt_token', jwt_token);
```

[My Error Log Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUKQM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Promise is not handled correctly..

Try to add a catch after your then call like this:

```
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Or try to use your function like this maybe:

```
      await getData("jwt_token")
    .then(data => data)
    .then(value => this.setState({ token: value })) // here it is setState but I guess you can also return
    .catch(err => console.log("AsyncStorageErr: " + err));
```

Comment: Mh did appending .catch() after your .then() where you return item did not change anything? same the second code is the error still the same?

Comment: In did append .catch(), still gets me error. i could use the second solution but the file is only for functions only, it doesn't have the react import

Comment: Ok and if you just use your function where you get the error and add a second .then? so before the .then(item => return item) maybe add a .then(data => data)

Comment: late reply. I don't having an error right now, thank you so much!

Comment: No worries dude gl :)